# Content Editor Web Part not loading Content Link

Tags: content-editor-web-part

I have a Content Editor Web Part, pointing to an html file at the web app's root (Content Link = "/Style Library/MyCollaborationWebParts/MyCollaborationLinks.html"). The content showed by the CEWP however is an old version of the html file.

To be clear, the site containing the CEWP has been created by backup and restore, or some other such process. It originally had no Content Link value; yet it showed an old version of the html file. I filled it in recently, and  the content showed did not change at all.

I have cleared my browser's cache.

I have clicked on the "preview" link and confirmed that I could see the html file

It might be of interest that the CEWP is sitting inside another CEWP

Comment: are you saying that you have updated the html file but its not updating on the cewp? I know it might sound stupid but have you tried ctrl + F5 ?

Comment: well, not in that order i suppose... it had the content of the old version of the html in the CEWP, and i updated the CEWP with the url of the html... ill update with further details.

Comment: yes i've tried ctrl-f5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of actually figuring out why my CEWP wasn't working, I simply replaced it with a Page Viewer Web Part, which was far more suited for the job. Unfortunately that meant deleting 42 CEWPs and replacing them with PVWPs, but it was worth it.

I would still like to know why the CEWP provides this functionality if it does not fully work and if the PVWP is more appropriate for the task.

Answer (score 0):

ok how are you linking up the url of the html file to the cewp? is it in the document lirary? if not you should put it in there. then get the url from that and put that as the link in cewp. You can then update the html file in the document library and it will update the cewp every time.

Comment: updated... sorry im not being very clear :\